# How do I identify Exchange mailboxes that don't belong to members of particular AD groups?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Our organization has Azure AD with 10 regional AD groups and 10K+ of other groups. My ASP.NET Core web app needs to report on the total mailbox size for each of the regional groups and report on the total size of mailbox for mailboxes that don't belong to any of the regional groups.

I'm using PowerShell to get the mailbox sizes (Get-EXOMailbox, Get-EXOMailboxStatistics) and
Graph SDK for AD data. Currently I export statistics + ExternalDirectoryObjectId for every mailbox to a DB table. I know how to get the statistics for the regional groups because the group members are all users and so Get-EXOMailbox().ExternalDirectoryObjectId refers to the AD User Id.

1. How do I identify the mailboxes that don't (indirectly) belong to one of the regional groups?
2. Is it possible to get the list of all mailboxes from Graph SDK instead of calling "Get-EXOMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are a numbers of way you could do this, the easiest would be the check the transitive membership of the user https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-transitivememberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. Doing that on a large number of users can be quite slow so as you only have 10 groups you may find it just better to expand the group membership first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http then do a local lookup.
2. No there is no substitute for Get-EXOMailbox in the Graph outside of what you can do with the users endpoint which is limited in terms of mailbox properites, maybe the closest to what your doing with Get-EXOMailboxStatistics would be the reporting endpoints https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailbox-usage-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Thanks. I assume that mailboxes will belong to entities other than an AD user entity? If so then which other AD entities do I need to check via Graph SDK?

Comment: Depends on the type of Mailbox eg a Shared Mailbox, Room Mailbox or equipment mailbox you won't have an accessible object via the Graph. For User mailboxes the underlying AAD object would be assessable via the Graph SDK. If you want to do anything with online archive (eg reporting sizes) then the Graph doesn't provide and level of reporting for this.